# Update Trigger after an Insert in SQL Server c#

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Here's the scenario I've been stuck on:

- User INSERTS a book into books table
- Books Collection UPDATES with the userid and the INSERTED bookid in bookscollection

Userid is passed from a string username in c# application.

```
bookcollection bookc_id, bookc_bookid, bookc_bookuser
books bookid, title, author, year
users userid, username, password
```

bookid is foreign key to bookc_bookid

userid is a foreign key to bookc_bookuser

This is how it gets inserted into books table

```
INSERT INTO books (title, author, year) VALUES (@title, @author, @year);
```

In a previous form I have used INNER JOIN clause to retrieve information from books collection based on the logged in Username string.

```
 SELECT * FROM bookcollection c 
 INNER JOIN users r ON c.bookC_userid = r.userid 
 INNER JOIN books b ON c.bookC_bookID = b.bookid 
 WHERE username LIKE '" + Username + "'"
```

**How could I create a trigger which would update the `books` table with the userid and bookid.**

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can create a update Trigger Like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER yourtriggername
     ON yourtablename
     AFTER  INSERT
AS
BEGIN
 /* here goes your update statement*/
   UPDATE c
   SET c.bookC_userid = r.userid,
   b.bookC_bookID= b.bookid 
   FROM bookcollection c 
   INNER JOIN users r ON c.bookC_userid = r.userid 
   INNER JOIN books b ON c.bookC_bookID = b.bookid
   Where b.bookid = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
end
```

**Edit:** You can get newly inserted id of yourtable by `Scope_Identity` function

Comment: Hey thanks for replying what does this mean` Where b.bookid = newlyinsertedbookid;` because I don't have newlyinsertedbookid how would it know? Also, another question, AFTER UPDATE, I thought it would be after INSERT because the trigger is meant to start after insert? sorry if these questions are stupid just intrigued

Comment: thankyou another question, because i have a string in my c# application is there any way i could include in that trigger?

Comment: because other wise there's no way of knowing who inserted it

Comment: @1234566543 : in trigger you can not pass parameter directly like stored procedure ..it will be better if you craeate a table and store in it who inserted in the insert statement and get the value in trigger

Comment: Shouldn't you somehow reference the `Inserted`  pseudo table in order to know **what new rows** have been added, when you update other stuff ?? The use of `SCOPE_IDENTITY` would only get the **last** inserted identity value - but an `INSERT` could have inserted 20 rows - how are you going to deal with **all 20 rows** in the `Inserted` table when using `SCOPE_IDENTITY` ????